# File access denied and previously functioning file now not working

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, permissions, administrator, file-corruption

I have Windows 7 on my Laptop.
I created a folder on my Desktop. I have been having problems with Administrator permissions on files and folders in it - requiring Administrator permission although I do not have any other user profiles (?)

I cut and pasted a file from the desktop to this folder.

Two things have now gone wrong now:

1) When I try to open it is gives me an error message saying:

Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

2) I try to undo the cut and paste it says I need Administrator permission

I went to look at the Windows help and created a new Administrator user profile and changed the Ownership for the file, but I still cannot open it - and I do NOT have a backup of this file [records for all of 2016!!! - don't ask.... :-( ]

Note: I did not change the file extension so there is no reason for the file extension to be wrong all of the sudden. And I do not know how to verify if the file has been corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If the file has been corrupted, the following may recover it:

1. First start up Excel
2. Click `File > Open`
3. Navigate to the folder path where the Excel sheet is located and click on the file in question
4. Click on the little arrow on the right side of the Open button, as shown in the image below, and select `Open and Repair`

[image: Open and Repair]

5. First try selecting the `Repair` option.
6. If `Repair` does not recover any of your data, choose `Extract Data` in order to salvage whatever data it is able to recover.

Comment: Thank you very much for that.....BUT this is what it displays:
You don't have permission to open this file.

Comment: ...I will try opening it in the other user profile I created...

Comment: Have you tried explicitly giving that user account full modify rights in the file properties of that file?

Comment: Ok, I have tried it...NO SUCCESS. Now, even though I have created this secondary user profile to transfer the Ownership, it says I do not have permission to open this file !!!!!

Comment: If this is an important file, I'd say create a live Linux USB drive. Boot up into Linux and grab that file from there and see if it'll open in Libre Office. Or possibly even upload it to Google Docs and see if it'll open there.

Answer (score 0):

go to HKEY-LOCAL-MACHINE\SOFWARE\POLICIES\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\WINDOWS UPDATE\
Delete the subkey AU now you should be good

Comment: Please provide a reference and explain how this answer the question.